# What does "implications" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> They [heralds] presided at the weddings and funerals of armigerous
>   families, so as to keep straight ***the implications*** of those
>   generational comings and goings for family pedigrees. (Tittler,
>   Robert., Portraits, Painters, and Publics in Provincial England
>   (1540-1640), p104)

What does "the implications" means in here? Is possible it refers to a genealogical concept? Honestly, I do not understand its semantic relation with whole of the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a herald, it was important to keep track of changes to family arms. The common way these changes occurred was due to two things: marriage and death.

The implications mentioned are the changes that weddings and funerals were bound to have to the correct representation of the arms of the involved families and individuals.

Comment: What synonym do you use instead of "implications" in here? I ask it because I need to translate the sentence to other language and I have a huge problem with finding a good equivalent.

Comment: The _effects_ or maybe the _results_ would do the trick, I think?